# User creationg error ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Getting this error (I have looked at the other stackoverflow posts). I am using permit but still not working?

These are the params in the signup form (first name, last name, phone, email, password, cc#, ccv, exp month, exp year)

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError): 
Nov 20 10:56:20 burro-staging app/web.1:    app/controllers/requester_controller.rb:400:in `new' 
Nov 20 10:56:20 burro-staging app/web.1:    app/controllers/requester_controller.rb:400:in `create'
```

Here is the code

```
def create
attributes = params[:user]
@user = User.new(book_params) 
@cc_number = params[:cc_number]
@cc_cvv = params[:cc_cvv]
@cc_exp_month = params[:cc_exp_month]
@cc_exp_year = params[:cc_exp_year]
all_required = true
.....

attributes[:type] = User::PATIENT
last4 = nil
begin
  last4 = params[:cc_number].gsub(/[^0-9]/i, '')[-4..-1]
rescue
  last4 = nil
end
attributes[:last_4_credit_card] = last4
attributes[:cc_exp_date] = "#{params[:cc_exp_month]}#  {params[:cc_exp_year]}"
r = User.create_new(book_params) <-- line 400
end

private
  def book_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:utf8, :authenticity_token, :cc_number, :cc_cvv, :cc_exp_month, :cc_exp_year, :email, :password, :last_name, :phone, :first_name)
  end
```

MY MODEL

```
def self.create_new(attributes)
    u = User.where(:email => attributes[:email].strip).first
 ....
end
```

Comment: try to debug it on development or other environment that you can get actual params you passed to the controller (usually in server log) to confirm that you have passed correct parameter format to controller

Comment: `type` is a reserved keyword. http://www.rubymagic.org/posts/ruby-and-rails-reserved-words is the link. Use some other attr name

Comment: The above code is correct. Browser was cashing.